# Gmail api response headers - getting information contained in angle brackets (php library)

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am using the gmail api and when I try to get the "From" field from a specific message, I get the name portion but not the address. Here is the query that works in the oauth2 playground:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14jj4883c9e195a8?format=metadata&metadataHeaders=From&fields=payload%2CsizeEstimate

It outputs:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "mimeType": "multipart/mixed",
        "headers": [
            {
                "name": "From",
                "value": "First Last <email@example.org>"
            }
        ]
    },
    "sizeEstimate": 180758
}
```

Implementing the same query in php:

```
function getMessage($service, $userId, $messageId) {
  try {
    $optParamsGet = array();    
    $optParamsGet['format'] = 'metadata';
    $optParamsGet['metadataHeaders'] = 'From';
    $optParamsGet['fields'] = 'payload,sizeEstimate';

    $message = $service->users_messages->get($userId, $messageId, $optParamsGet);
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' retrieved.<br>';
    return $message;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

$message2 = getMessage($service,$userId,$message_id);

            if ($message2->getPayload()) {
                $headers = $message2->getPayload()->getHeaders(); 
                foreach ($headers as $header) {
                    if ('From' == $header->name) {
                        $name_value = $header->value;
                        echo $name_value . "<br>";
                        array_push($sendernames,$name_value);
                        echo $header['value']. "<br>";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } 
            var_dump($headers);
```

And now, doing a var_dump on the headers in the returned $message does not show the email address within the angle bracket. How do I get this?

Comment: If you're `echo`-ing the value directly to an HTML document, you're going to want to pipe it through `htmlspecialchars()`, eg `echo htmlspecialchars($name_value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value should definitely be there in the from header.  I agree with phil, I think it's likely your "<" and ">" are getting hidden/removed since you're printing to html output source.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just used regex to get the email from the 
`"First Last <email@example.org>"` 
 as far as I saw there was nowhere in the headers that had just the email address